# How to decide if an URL should be encoded or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using `URLs` downloaded from the Internet, so I don't know their format in advance and they are dynamic.

How to know if I should encode an `URL` at run time?

```
// `url` is retrieved from the Internet at run time
// When should I call following line?
let urlString = url!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())
```

If it's already encoded, calling `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` will make the `URL` invalid.

Comment: you could check the string and make a broad assumption that if it contains a '%' character its already been encoded?

Comment: A URL must always be correctly encoded. Strictly, there's no such thing like an unencoded URL. You might verify if the URL is valid using the helper class `NSURLComponents`.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper It does happen for non-English URLs

Comment: @JoeHuang No, a URL is either valid or invalid - with respect to its characters. See [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). So basically, there must be no invalid characters within the URL. Characters which are "not safe" need to be escaped.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper For example, when I get an URL that is in non-English, it is a valid one (I can put it in the browser and open it), but if I don't encode it before passing it to `NSURL`, it will crash. How to avoid this situation?

Comment: @JoeHuang NSRUL will _only_ accept valid URL strings. Browsers may apply fancy heuristics to figure out what was meant actually and automatically correct the URL. A URL that contains non-ASCII characters is not valid. It's always ambiguous and error prone to "fix" a bogus URL. I would not recommend to do that.  So, in your case you should try to fix the issue at the root where it originates. Otherwise, _check_ if the URL is valid using `NSURLComponents`. If it is invalid - don't use it.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper What you mean is that non-English URLs are not valid? Even if I check with `NSURLComponents`, it will tell me that it's invalid and I should not open that URL?

Comment: Use `NSURLComponents` [init?(string URLString: String)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLComponents_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLComponents/initWithString:) method. If the initialiser returns `nil`, the URL could not be parsed into its components.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper In this way, `NSURLComponents` returns nil for non-English URLs, which means I cannot open them. However, I have to find a way to validate them, or it's not a correct bahavior for my app. Those URLs are downloaded from Facebook API, I do think I should open them instead of showing some error to the user.

Comment: @JoeHuang I don't think its easy to "correct" invalid URLs. You would need to write your own parser. Simply applying `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is not reliable. You can however just _try_ the URL -- if you can successfully init an NSURL with this string. But basically, you should simply accept the fact, that a URL might be invalid. It's unfortunate that this comes from a popular web-site.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Here is my solution. Validate the URL with `NSURL` or `NSURLComponents`, and if `nil` is returned, encode the URL. Validate the encoded URL, if it is still nil, show some error UI message. Do you think any flaw in here?

Comment: @JoeHuang You _can_ do this, but you need to accept the fact, that applying `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to a malformed URL does NOT reliably heal it. It may even return a semantically incorrect URL - even when you can successfully create a NSURL with the encoded string. You really should read [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use:`NSString *unencodedUrlString = [originalURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` to decode the URL. Now compare the decoded version with the original. If they are the same, the url is not encoded, otherwise it is already encoded.

Comment: This will not work if any of the decoded components contains a `%` character.